# Docker load image is not working on Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-image

I am trying to load images using Docker for Windows 10, but that is not working at all. I am getting an error message after loading the images from Docker.

```
    re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage
 C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\70c499c5f2bcb13f46e5b648e18a5fa145c38d3e92db8bbd91ca93c85ae83502\UtilityVM:
 winapi error #3489661090
```

Anyone has gone through this problem and any fixes/solutions.

```
PS C:\> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Docker Info:

```
PS C:\> Docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.693.amd64fre.rs1_release.161220-1747)
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.425 GiB
Name: INLT-F40841FD
ID: OZLH:C6F2:OC2O:XNZF:5547:OYR5:AEBT:VWLI:SY3C:VN2D:V5QW:JBOA
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 17
 System Time: 2017-05-03T10:04:02.7562191+05:30
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```